# Rstudio fails to open with error "...could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb""

Tags: 14.04, rstudio

RStudio on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS fails to open and gives the following error message:

```
rstudio
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What is wrong? RStudio is not opening.

Comment: Do you have an xcb library installed? IIRC correctly, RStudio depends on having one installed.  `sudo apt-get install libxcb1 libx11-xcb1`

Comment: yes "libxcb1" is already installed to newest version.